# Negating multiple queues in Sun Grid Engine (SGE)

Tags: regex, sungridengine

When specifying your destination queues for a Sun Grid Engine job submission, is it possible to negate multiple destinations?

Typically I will have something like:

```
#$ -q *@!chrom*
```

Which will run on every host/queue which doesn't match the pattern "chrom*". What if I wanted to run on every machine except for "chrom*" and "reef", for example? All the documentation I can find suggests that SGE should support this (they support ORs and multiple patterns), however all my attempts thus-far have met with failure.

Some things I've tried:

```
*@(!chrom*|!oryza*)
*@!chrom,*@!oryza*
```

(and so on).

Is there something simple I'm overlooking here? The best documentation I've found of their pattern matching is here, under "Matching Types": http://linux.die.net/man/1/sge_types

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like the following should work:
`*@!(chrom|orzya|reef)`

Comment: Not sure why you were downvoted for trying to help, but unfortunately this doesn't appear to work. I used `-q *@!(chrom|oryza|reef)` and it was still run in the `oryza` queue. Thanks for the reply!

Comment: I commented too soon. The solution was to use wildcards since I forgot that this is matching hostnames not queue names. `-q *@!(chrom*|oryza*|reef)` does exactly what I need. Thank you!

Comment: *@(chrom|orzya|reef) would match any of the three hosts.  Adding the exclamation mark in front of the ! negates the host part of the expression.